Редирект на другой домен
Исходное:

есть шаред хостинг, на котором лежит фронт
к нему привязан домен demo-1.ru
с этого фронта делаются запросы на demo-api.ru
апи запущена на vds с nginx

Задача:
при переходе на demo-2.ru нужно редиректить на demo-1.ru
Очевидной идеей кажется: на шере добавить еще один сайт, на него привязать домен demo-2.ru, настроить редирект в апаче, но тариф добавить еще один сайт не позволяет
Кажется хорошей идей что-то попробовать на vds, но как это сделать не представляю, ибо опыта работы с nginx мало. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно сделать?
Конфиг:
server {
    server_name demo-api.ru;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://unix:/var/run/gunicorn/demo-api.sock;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    error_log /root/demo-api/logs/nginx_error.log;
    access_log /root/demo-api/logs/nginx_access.log;

}


Если можно привязать к IP ещё один домен, то надо это сделать и добавить в конфиг nginx ещё один блок server с редиректом
